# Why doesn't this NSSet member method work?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsset

I have an `NSSet` with `@"x"` in the set and I'm trying to use the instance method `member:` to check for it, like so:

```
NSSet *everythingOnStack = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:program, nil];
NSSet *variablesOnStack =  [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:([everythingOnStack member:@"x"]),nil];   

NSLog(@"Variables on, %@",variablesOnStack);
NSLog(@"Everything on stack,%@",everythingOnStack);
```

The `member:` method doesn't seem to see the `@"x"` and I'm not sure why.  Below is the `NSLog()` output. I read the documentation and it seems it should work. Confused.

```
2012-05-21 20:43:07.902 Calculator[21589:f803] Variables on, {(
)}
2012-05-21 20:43:07.904 Calculator[21589:f803] Everything on stack,{(
    (
    1,
    2,
    x,
    "+"
)
)}
```

I'm learning Objective C by going through the Stanford online class.

Answer (score 3):

The string `@"x"` *isn't* a member of `everythingOnStack`. It's a member of whatever kind of collection `program` is (looks like an array). When you do `[everythingOnStack member:@"x"]` (the parentheses are unecessary, by the way), you get `nil` back, so you end up with an empty set for `variablesOnStack`.

In order to get `@"x"` out of `everythingOnStack`, you will have to get it out of the `program` array:

```
[[everythingOnStack member:program] objectAtIndex:3]
```

note that this requires you to know where the object you want is in the array. I'm not sure how that affects your design -- looks like you're maybe implementing an RPN calculator?

Comment: Yes I am implementing a calculator.. going through the Stanford online class in iTunes U.  Awesome class.  In the class, the parenthesis were recommended.  By using the right NSSet initialization, see below, the member method is now working perfectly. Thanks for your help.  If I had enough points I would vote you up.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you might be misunderstanding what this line does: [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:program, nil];  This adds one object, the array "program" to your set, it doesn't add each of the objects in "program" to your set. If you want to add each member of the array to your set, you can use NSSet *everythingOnStack = [NSSet setWithArray:program];

If done, this way, then "x" will be a member of your set.  However, you will get a uniqued set (all sets are I think), so if you had the same number in "program" twice, it would only show up once in the set.

Comment: Well Shoot I wish I had enough points to vote you up. You're exactly right.  
`
NSSet *everythingOnStack = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:program];
'

Works Great now!!